# Self hosted WCF net.tcp service app fails to start intermittently

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting, etw, net.tcp

We have a windows service that listens on a WCF port.  The service starts up and successfully binds to the port maybe 25% of the time.  This is happening on 2 different machines.  This code has been stable for some time, the only difference may be that we re-targetted to .NET 4.6.2 while back, but we're not completely sure if it had anything to do with this.  When it fails we get the following:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Provider type not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090017)
File name: 'System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase..ctor()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Object singletonInstance, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at PSC.Tools.Communication.ListeningExecutorServerWCF.OnStart()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/FieldAssist/Server/binaries/Links/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

As you can see from the binding log info, it does look like it successfully resolved the assembly.  Anyone have any ideas?

The line of code throwing the exception is:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance);
```

Where serviceInstance is an instance of a class (so that we set up a singleton).